# how do i do an incremental import into a 9i database

Tags: import, oracle11g, append, oracle9i, datapump

I need to carry out the append feature of the impdp utility while importing a 11g database dump into a 9i database. I also need to be able to do it the other way round for importing into a 11g database from a 9i database using the same append feature of the impdp utility.

From what i find, the data pump client is not compatible with the 9i database, so this append feature is not available to me. Is there a way I can get around this?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

To move data between a 9i and 11g database you would need to use the [original export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm) and [original import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm) utilities rather than datapump.

Since you want to move data between different versions, [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1013164) is very relevant:

> Whenever you are moving data between different releases of the Oracle
>   database, the following basic rules apply:
>
> - The Import utility and the database to which data is being imported (the target database) must be the same version. For example, if you
>     try to use the Import utility 9.2.0.7 to import into a 9.2.0.8
>     database, then you may encounter errors.
> - The version of the Export utility must be equal to the version of either the source or target database, whichever is earlier.
>
> For example, to create an export file for an import into a later
>   release database, use a version of the Export utility that equals the
>   source database. Conversely, to create an export file for an import
>   into an earlier release database, use a version of the Export utility
>   that equals the version of the target database.

So to move data from 9i to 11g, you need to export with the 9i binaries and import with the 11g binaries. To move data from 11g to 9i, you need to do both the export and import using the 9i binaries; which means you need a 9i environment which has access to the 11g database. If they are on different servers you'd need to either do a export from your 9i environment accessing the 11g database remotely, or have a 9i installation on the 11g server, at the same patch level as the target environment.

Moving data from 11g to 9i seems an odd thing to want to do, given how old 9i is, and how long it has been out of support.

To cover your original question about behaviour similar to `append`, from [the import documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1023662):

> When tables are manually created before data is imported, the CREATE
>   TABLE statement in the export dump file will fail because the table
>   already exists. To avoid this failure and continue loading data into
>   the table, set the Import parameter IGNORE=y. Otherwise, no data will
>   be loaded into the table because of the table creation error.

`imp` doesn't have a `truncate` option, so data is always appended onto whatever is there; not without that [`IGNORE=Y` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#autoId38) the import will fail because the *object* exists, rather than because there is data in it.